# Session doesn't work when accessed from address

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm using Codeigniter 3 and the sessions work fine during a website visit, but if I try to access it from the address bar the session isn't detected and only is when I click a link inside the website

here is my home controller:

```
<?php
session_start();
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Accueil extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }
    public function index()
    {
        if (isset($_SESSION['userID'])) {
            $this->load->model('User_model', 'u');
            $user         = $this->u->userInfo($_SESSION['userID']);
            $data['user'] = $user[0];
            $this->load->view('home', $data);
        } else
            $this->reception();

    }
    public function reception()
    {
        $this->load->view('categories');
    }

}
```

Comment: It's normal it's the principe of a session, you should test the cookies instead.

Comment: @Arlien print_r($_COOKIES) doesn't return cookies I set neither.

Answer (score 0):

first of all load session library in auto load 
then set session like

```
  $this->session->set_userdata("id",$id);

  and get session like

  $this->session->userdata(id);
```